# How to display data in a recyclerview using FirebaseUI?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am new to firebase and I am in love with this real-time database thing.
However, I am not sure how to display nested data in a recycled view.
Following is my database structure :-[image]

I want to display the data at 0,1,2...The data consist of information about different books.
This is what I have tried so far:-

```
    private void getSelectedBooks() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BooksInfo, BooksViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BooksInfo, BooksViewHolder>(
                BooksInfo.class,
                R.layout.book_list,
                BooksViewHolder.class,
                nextOrder.child(String.valueOf(index))
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BooksViewHolder viewHolder, final BooksInfo model, final int position) {

                Log.d("BOOKDETAILS",model.getTitle());
//                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
//                viewHolder.setISBN(model.getISBN());
//                viewHolder.setDiscount(model.get());
//                viewHolder.setQty(model.getQuantity());
//                viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
//                viewHolder.setGrossValue(model.get);
//                viewHolder.setNetValue(model.get);


                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        DatabaseReference ref = getRef(position);
                        String key = ref.getKey();
                        Toast.makeText(AddOrderActivity.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                        getRetailerInfo(key);


                    }
                });
            }
        };

        selectedBookRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(index)).exists()) {
                    // run some code
//                    DisableProgress();
                } else {
//                    DisableProgress();
//                    Toast.makeText(RetailerActivity.this, "No retailers to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here  `DatabaseReference nextOrder = mDatabase.child(userId).child("order_details").child(String.valueOf(index));`

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.